# Generate dates based on condition before and after index dates

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, lubridate

I have a data frame with 10,000+ dates. for example,

```
indexdt
01-02-2019
08-15-2019
```

I need to create two data frames based on the following conditions-

1. generate dates such that I get same day of week, upto 3 weeks before and after the index date. The out put should be

```
Table 1

    indexdt dates
    01-02-2019  12-26-2018
    01-02-2019  12-19-2018
    01-02-2019  12-12-2018
    01-02-2019  01-09-2019
    01-02-2019  01-16-2019
    01-02-2019  01-23-2019
    08-15-2019  07-25-2019
    08-15-2019  08-01-2019
    08-15-2019  08-08-2019
    08-15-2019  08-22-2019
    08-15-2019  08-29-2019
    08-15-2019  08-05-2019
```

2. same day of week, same month.  The output should be

```
Table 2

    indexdt     date
    01-02-2019  01-09-2019
    01-02-2019  01-16-2019
    01-02-2019  01-23-2019
    01-02-2019  01-30-2019
    08-15-2019  08-01-2019
    08-15-2019  08-08-2019
    08-15-2019  08-22-2019
    08-15-2019  08-29-2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have answered both the questions here but you should only ask one question in one post :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

#Convert to date
df <- df %>% mutate(indexdt = mdy(indexdt))
```

1. generate dates such that I get same day of week, upto 3 weeks before and after the index date

We use `seq` to generate before and after dates separately. `[-1]` is used to ignore the `indexdt` date since we don't want that in final output.

```
df %>%
  mutate(dates = map(indexdt, ~c(seq(.x, length.out = 4, by = -7)[-1], 
                                 seq(.x, length.out = 4, by = 7)[-1]))) %>%
  unnest(dates)


#   indexdt    dates     
#   <date>     <date>    
# 1 2019-01-02 2018-12-26
# 2 2019-01-02 2018-12-19
# 3 2019-01-02 2018-12-12
# 4 2019-01-02 2019-01-09
# 5 2019-01-02 2019-01-16
# 6 2019-01-02 2019-01-23
# 7 2019-08-15 2019-08-08
# 8 2019-08-15 2019-08-01
# 9 2019-08-15 2019-07-25
#10 2019-08-15 2019-08-22
#11 2019-08-15 2019-08-29
#12 2019-08-15 2019-09-05
```

2. same day of week, same month.

Here we create a sequence from `indexdt` date to start of the month (`floor_date`) and another sequence from `indexdt` to end of the month (`ceiling_date - 1`).

```
df %>%
  mutate(dates = map(indexdt, ~c(seq(.x, floor_date(.x, 'month'), by = -7)[-1],
                        seq(.x, ceiling_date(.x, 'month') - 1, by = 7)[-1]))) %>%
  unnest(dates)

#  indexdt    dates     
#  <date>     <date>    
#1 2019-01-02 2019-01-09
#2 2019-01-02 2019-01-16
#3 2019-01-02 2019-01-23
#4 2019-01-02 2019-01-30
#5 2019-08-15 2019-08-08
#6 2019-08-15 2019-08-01
#7 2019-08-15 2019-08-22
#8 2019-08-15 2019-08-29
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(indexdt = c("01-02-2019", "08-15-2019")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thanks Ronak.  I am a new user and I wasn't aware that I should be posting one problem in one post...though it makes sense.  Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Comment: Would you also be able to give a solution in data.table?  Thanks.

Comment: If you need an answer in `data.table`, you should have mentioned in your original post. You can ask a new question for that.

Comment: Thanks again Ronak.  I should have mentioned it in my post.  I will post a new question.